# Decimal in Windows Forms / declaring & textbox use

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm rather new to c# and programming in general, started working on a windows forms app due to a project.

I have worker with strings and `datatime` types, but i'm not sure how i'm supposed to declare a `decimal`, and then use it in the `textbox`.

My testclass which works, but no `decimal`

```
internal class Customer
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public Customer(string lastName, string firstName, DateTime     birthDate)
    {
        LastName = lastName;
        FirstName = firstName;
        BirthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

In the actual Form I use a `foreach` with the first column as the main item and then the next ones as subitems

```
var listViewItem = new   ListViewItem(customer.LastName);
listViewItem.SubItems.Add(customer.FirstName);
listViewItem.SubItems.Add(customer.BirthDate.ToShortDateString());
```

So `string` is pretty straight forward, `datetime` gets .`ToShortDateString()`, what do I do with the damn `decimal`?

And when I add items to my form I use this for the `button` `click` event

```
string firstName = tbFirstName.Text;
string lastName = tbLastName.Text;
DateTime birthDate =     dtpBirthDate.Value;

var customer = new Customer(lastName, firstName, birthDate);
    _customers.Add(customer);
```

Same here, `string` gets`.text`, `date` gets `.value` but I really have no idea how to implement a `decimal` :/

Thanks and sorry if this badly structured, I'm on my phone and trying to copy snippets.

Comment: Where are you going to use decimal value. You have declared string and datetime only

Comment: Basically in the class, form and the button click. I left it out because I don't even know how to properly declare it ( i think ), thus I couldn't properly use it like the other ones, so I removed it completely. This was the only version I could access, and I have tried looking everywhere. I only found stuff about validation in textbox but I can't even get there with it

Comment: `public decimal Foo { get; set;}` When you want to get a decimal value from a textbox (or string in general). `Decimal.Parse` or `Decimal.TryParse`

Comment: @Thoe332 so, your question is "How to retrieve value from DateTimePicker into property `BirthDate` of class `Customer`?"

Comment: No, sorry if I can't seem to ask the right question. I have 2 strings and a datetime, and I want to add a decimal to use it as I've used the other ones but don't know how. I want to use the decimal in my foreach and in my button event, and I don't know how to convert it